# Can the warranty on a laptop be transferred to a new owner?

Tags: warranties, security

I'm currently interested in selling my laptop so that I can use the money to help purchase one that better satisfies my needs. It's still in very good condition (no mark or dents) and has only been used for a year. I have bought a 3-year warranty on it which I had purchased with the device from the local supply retail chain and I still possess the receipt for it, so I'm hoping I can recoup some of the cost back by offering both the product and the warranty. Would the new owner of the device be able to utilize the warranty if I give him the receipt? Could there be a security issue if my receipt no longer falls under my possession (I had paid for it with credit card and the receipt mentions the authorization number, which card I had used, and the last 4 digits of the card)?

Comment: Not an answer, but another option would be to cancel the warranty and ask for a (partial) refund. Some warranties allow that - for example, AppleCare+ for Macintosh Computers will give you pro-rata refund, minus a cancellation fee.

Answer (score 2):

Many warranties include explicit provisions indicating whether they protect later owners, or run only to the original purchaser. Some go one way, some the other. The explicit warranty provisions should be consulted.

Answer (score -3):

Warranties transfer to a new owner automatically - they are part of the goods or service.

Comment: Surely that depends on whether they are a statutory warranty under consumer law, or an extended warranty which is a voluntary sale?  The OP says the warranty they are talking about is an extended warranty, so it's likely that the answer to its transferability is detailed in that warranties conditions.